# Spring integration dynamic trigger with cron expression

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I saw the sample dynamic trigger in github and it is using fixed rate/delay but is it possible to implement dynamic trigger with cron expression where once job is completed with custom exit code we want the cron expression in such a way that it no longer poll for that day or change cron expressin to start polling from diff time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger` uses `final` field, so we can't change its state at runtime. Therefore any ideas to seek the way how to change `cron-expression` value is a waste of time.

From other let's take a look at this as just a `time producer` solution to notify the scheduler when to start a provided task.

In other words here is a `Trigger` contract source code:

```
public interface Trigger {

    Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext);

}
```

So, what our solution must supply is just only returning the specific `Date` for each `nextExecutionTime` invocation.

Only what you need to do here is that `dynamic trigger` implementation which fits to your requirements.

Right, it might be a bit difficult to reach cron-similar behavior, but there is no choice for you right now...

Although you can `stop()` you adapter after the task, inject a new `CronTrigger` to it and `start()` it again.

Comment: But if you stop the adapater using control bus, how it would start next day without invoking thru some other apps. All we need is, let for day one, if job finished successfully then change next schedule time using dynamic trigger in a such a way that it goes to next day. So i believe extending DynamicTrigger is right way to go and just override nextscheduledTime method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom trigger that simply wraps a `CronTrigger` and you can replace the delegate `CronTrigger` at will.

However, a limitation of the `Trigger` mechanism is you can't change an existing schedule.

If you are running your job on the poller thread, then you can change the trigger before the poller thread returns (and calls the trigger to find the next execution time).

Spring Integration 4.2 (currently at milestone 2) has [conditional pollers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) which will make things like this a little easier.